Gunicorn error.log shows a error in the log but Gunicorn itself works
I have setup Nginx with gunciron and django. Everything seems to work fine , atleast that what i believed. However , when i check the .gunicorn-logs directory as specified to be created in docker and specified the myscipt.sh below, it shows 2 files :

access.log with all the access to the gunciron server &
error.log which should be empty shows 1 kb of file.

Upon inspection, I get this inside --->

Gunicorn error.log file --->
[2024-12-05 04:36:15 +0000] [85] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 23.0.0
[2024-12-05 04:36:15 +0000] [85] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8585 (85)
[2024-12-05 04:36:15 +0000] [85] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2024-12-05 04:36:15 +0000] [88] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 88
[2024-12-05 04:36:15 +0000] [89] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 89
[2024-12-05 04:36:15 +0000] [90] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90
[2024-12-05 04:36:15 +0000] [91] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 91

Gunciron access.log file --->
49.xxx.xxx.xx - - [05/Dec/2024:10:06:26 +0530] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4158 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2024:10:06:35 +0530] "GET /static/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2024:10:06:36 +0530] "GET /admin/login/?next=/static/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4172 "http://34.xxx.xxx.xx:75/static/admin/" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2024:10:06:42 +0530] "GET /static/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2024:10:06:42 +0530] "GET /admin/login/?next=/static/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4172 "http://34.xxx.xxx.xx:75/static/admin/" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0"

The nginx logs files has only access.log filled up and the error.log is empty.
Nginx access.log file ---->
49.xxx.xxx.xx - - [05/Dec/2024:04:36:35 +0000] "GET /static/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0" "-"
49.xxx.xxx.xx - - [05/Dec/2024:04:36:36 +0000] "GET /admin/login/?next=/static/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1522 "http://34.xxx.xxx.xx:75/static/admin/" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0" "-"
49.xxx.xxx.xx - - [05/Dec/2024:04:36:42 +0000] "GET /static/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0" "-"
49.xxx.xxx.xx - - [05/Dec/2024:04:36:42 +0000] "GET /admin/login/?next=/static/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1526 "http://34.xxx.xxx.xx:75/static/admin/" "PostmanRuntime/7.43.0" "-"

Here is how i have define the gunicorn server related lines inside dockerFile.
RUN mkdir -p .gunicorn-logs
RUN touch /opt/.gunicorn-logs/error.log
RUN touch /opt/.gunicorn-logs/access.log
RUN chmod +x /opt/.gunicorn-logs/
cmd myscipt.sh

The myscript.sh where both nginx and gunciron get invoked --->
#!/bin/sh
nginx -g 'daemon off;' & 
gunicorn mydjangoapi.wsgi:application --config=gunicorn_config_api-1.py

Finally , gunicorn_config_api-1.py part of root folder --->
bind = "0.0.0.0:8585"
loglevel = "INFO"
workers = "4"
threads="10"
reload = True

errorlog = "/opt/.gunicorn-logs/error.log"
accesslog = "/opt/.gunicorn-logs/access.log"


There is no error in those log files

Thanks Gerald for clarifying. Its my lack of knowledge of what Info log level was that led me in the direction.

When you set loglevel = "INFO" you are opting into [INFO]-severity messages. It is entirely expected that you see them, after having specifically asked for them.
